# Anaconda import mpi4py but not mpi

Tags: python, anaconda, mpi4py

I installed anaconda on 32 bit windows system.  Then installed the mpi4py package with conda install.

```
conda search mpi4py
Fetching package metadata .......
mpi4py                       2.0.0                    py27_0  defaults
                          *  2.0.0              py27_msmpi_0  mpi4py
                             2.0.0                    py34_0  defaults
                             2.0.0                    py35_0  defaults
```

The * should mean it is installed, right?

So in the anaconda terminal prompt, I can run python and do

```
import mpi4py
```

with no errors.

However,

```
from mpi4py import MPI
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The conda repository for mpi4py did not have any more instructions, which makes me think there is some issue here with the configuration.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have Microsoft MPI installed on your system. Did you get the following message when you did `conda install mpi4py`?

> mpi4py requires that Microsoft MPI 6 be installed on the host
>   system. That is a systemwide installation that is currently
>   not available through conda. In order to successfully use
>   mpi4py you must install Microsoft MPI and then append the bin
>   directory of the MPI installation to your PATH environment
>   variable. To install Microsoft MPI see
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47259

Try downloading that installer and try again.

Comment: I thought i had done that, the problem was related to the order I think.  I already had the conda mpi4py and it wouldnt reinstall, so it never saw the mpi for some reason.